# Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

don't support null safety:

- package:provider_mvc
- package:provider

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:472:9)
#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/src/javascript_bundle.dart:153:33)

#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:694:47)

#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:602:9)

#4      listenAndCompile. (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1199:11)

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile the application.

Comment: please describe your problem and put some code so people can understand whats the matter here

Comment: Check this out https://pub.dev/packages/provider/versions/5.0.0-nullsafety.1/install

Comment: for the other package there is no null safety available